# Laravel Passport not handling website's own API call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am using `Laravel 5.4` and `AngularJS`. I have created `APIs` which are called by my own web-site's `AngularJS Ajax` methods, also by a `Mobile App` and also by some `Third-party apps`.

For `API authentication` I am using `Laravel Passport ~4.0`, with `Password Grant`. Every is working OK with the `API` calls, but I am not able to `authenticate` the `API` using `Ajax` calls from my Web-site.

As per the [Laravel Passport Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript), if I use the provider `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class`, in `web` middleware group, then I don't need to set the `Authorization Header` for my own `API` calls, `Laravel` will handle it for me. *(See #Consuming Your API With JavaScript Para:2 in the provided link)*

Please review my code implementation below:

**config/app.php:**

```
<?php
    return [
        'providers' => [
            Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class
        ]
    ];
```

**app/models/User.php:**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use App\Traits\Encryptable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens;
        use SoftDeletes;
        use Notifiable;
        use Encryptable;

        protected $table = 'users';
    }
```

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php:**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Providers;
    use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

    class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

        protected $policies = [
            'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        ];

        public function boot(){
            $this->registerPolicies();
            Passport::routes();
        }
    }
```

**config/auth.php:**

```
<?php
    return [
        'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'passport',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

**routes/api.php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, mobile-app' );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1','middleware'=>['auth:api']], function () {
        //Some APIs are here which returns JSON
    });
```

**routes/web.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, mobile-app' );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

    Route::get('/',function(){
        if(\Auth::check()){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        return redirect('/login');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => array('auth')], function(){
        //Some web routes here which returns html views
    });
```

**app/http/Kernel.php**

```
<?php 
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => 
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],
    ];
```

An Ajax request I am doing using `AngularJS` is as:

```
function makeRequest(url, params, method) {
    var requestUrl = '/' + url;
    if(params != null){
       var requestUrl = '/' + url+'?page=1';  
    }
    angular.forEach(params, function(value, key){
        requestUrl = requestUrl + '&' + key + '=' + value;
    });
    return $http({
        'url': requestUrl,
        'method': method,
        'headers': {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        'cache': false
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    }).catch(dataServiceError);
}
```

With requesting `/dashboard` page which returns an html `view`, `Request` and `Response` is as:

```
General:

    Request URL: http://local.something.com/dashboard
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers: 

    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,gu;q=0.8
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: laravel_token=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%3D%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlpOcllLTDRkYmsrbmRhTnF6NFQ0Z0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiY2VES3d2VGhIcUlnczdOQmV4VzVISHpnUXRFS1lra2dHTXN5VmR0bEQweEVjejlFTFpRczNEdTNtSGRUdW1TS2IyTU01QVwvZCt2RVVmOHRHUUYrRzlBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5ZTZhMjE3ZGE2MTliNmNkMzg4ZTg5ODA0MTEyN2E4YTZhNTgxMWFhYWIwMTFhNTM5YWYzMjViMzMxOTkyNjU2In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IktlNUpPd0s2djRzQXlVakRuUkxUR3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicVwvSmlLaVpWK2hKSytQcUU5WmJCdmJIR2ZPS2JnT1FKbWY2M0VLOVNzYlBcL3pJYnl6c1RrVWFVQVlHWUNodjgzdk92WStRVDl1cHEzUGtPRStMUmhPZz09IiwibWFjIjoiODg4YzhmYjQ0NzE2ZDI2MWY1YmU2MmJiYjUxZjk0NTA5MmNiY2ZkZDEwYjk0OTFjZTY0MTE5ODk0MjZmYjRkMSJ9
    Host: local.something.com
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36

Response Headers:

    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, mobile-app
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Cache-Control: no-cache, private
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 06:21:59 GMT
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4
    Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjVWbGlOekVib1QycWFHMTlVb01ENnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibjQzNXFkME95MmMzekJ4cUNOSldpQXY4dE95YVlxV3dsMFNZc1hGZHQySk9lSE5MTXRiS1FJSVNiXC9cL0V4VEFQb1V0Qnl1V1FFb0RhM0Roa2xCVk9zZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMjJmZGRlNzU0MDBmNzA1MzdhYTRmMWNkMjM5YjBmYjU2YzMwOWM1OGFkNmMwYzQ3YTIwMTYzYzY1M2M5ZGZiMiJ9; expires=Mon, 07-May-2018 08:22:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
    Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InVPWUplcE1GZnVHNUYxXC9YMWl1UmtnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlQxUkpmVllhb0R2dkpiZDFWd0xlWXg5WGxjQTY5dFY2R3BjdGNvTVhoc1pORnE5b0ttMXhcL2NZbFErOVwvMnUwTDAwcFFLXC9ySzdaMkxSR1wva3NEMW1mUT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGYxYmM2NmNhMjE1NjliNGYzYmFiYTdhZmY2ZWY5NzM1MmI5ZjQ3ZTdlY2JjMDg5ODkxMWQwOTBiNjM2MDQzZSJ9; expires=Mon, 07-May-2018 08:22:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: laravel_token=eyJpdiI6ImYxdDB4SGpnWGptMnBNM3lWc2pvY0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRDZheEtEeHdPT2EyQWFuZ1NPOHcwSnRtUnZ3aW1jOVhxNGtBRnZQK01OakZaTmNIQ1JVMkJ4MGl3RjdhR0NzR0VVODlaWDNyTXVWOXpjS1lOOWNEeDh0OGxISnBWUnU4V0NwKzdheVN0bGJkSVk2dGNnYng3c1p1OGExVGFKejR1M2JjMGlSVzJ3WElEbEFlVTNUeVA1ODdTZXE5alBqWSs5aXV5UUlZVkRmSGppTm0zSnNZc2tEMEhzTEt2NEZ6K0t4eDI0WDdDUmJGYm44NGc4aXo4akxMRVFySmdZblwvMEtMZDJYVTFYU0pBVDY5RG9SdmhlaDF0REhONEpLNHNJbWppZWxrS1Nhd0ZjU2ZVazJqdCtBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkMmE1NTc4YTFhYTRlODFmOWY5YjllNmM1MDA4Nzg4ODg5Njg2NDI1Zjk3MzdkYmFlNzg2YzNkZjI3NzYzOWY0In0%3D; expires=Mon, 07-May-2018 08:22:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
```

And An API Request for getting User-data done using `Ajax` is like:

```
General:

Request URL: http://local.something.com/api/v1/user/3/data
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers:

accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,gu;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: laravel_token=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjVWbGlOekVib1QycWFHMTlVb01ENnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibjQzNXFkME95MmMzekJ4cUNOSldpQXY4dE95YVlxV3dsMFNZc1hGZHQySk9lSE5MTXRiS1FJSVNiXC9cL0V4VEFQb1V0Qnl1V1FFb0RhM0Roa2xCVk9zZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMjJmZGRlNzU0MDBmNzA1MzdhYTRmMWNkMjM5YjBmYjU2YzMwOWM1OGFkNmMwYzQ3YTIwMTYzYzY1M2M5ZGZiMiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InVPWUplcE1GZnVHNUYxXC9YMWl1UmtnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlQxUkpmVllhb0R2dkpiZDFWd0xlWXg5WGxjQTY5dFY2R3BjdGNvTVhoc1pORnE5b0ttMXhcL2NZbFErOVwvMnUwTDAwcFFLXC9ySzdaMkxSR1wva3NEMW1mUT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGYxYmM2NmNhMjE1NjliNGYzYmFiYTdhZmY2ZWY5NzM1MmI5ZjQ3ZTdlY2JjMDg5ODkxMWQwOTBiNjM2MDQzZSJ9
Host: local.something.com
Referer: http://local.something.com/dashboard
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IjVWbGlOekVib1QycWFHMTlVb01ENnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibjQzNXFkME95MmMzekJ4cUNOSldpQXY4dE95YVlxV3dsMFNZc1hGZHQySk9lSE5MTXRiS1FJSVNiXC9cL0V4VEFQb1V0Qnl1V1FFb0RhM0Roa2xCVk9zZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMjJmZGRlNzU0MDBmNzA1MzdhYTRmMWNkMjM5YjBmYjU2YzMwOWM1OGFkNmMwYzQ3YTIwMTYzYzY1M2M5ZGZiMiJ9

Response Headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, mobile-app
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 06:22:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im82TGNRVms0aUtSNHNVbzdKZXZYb0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiY1wvTmZXV3o0SVYyRmVoMzRheWNaRHBDV29jWmI2S3JvQjNBOEVjNHlsQkpKMWlRMWdYWlU1ckdnbTRIOVllSmZIOVpud01BTExtSURXNHdDdkZZMDNnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIyMzc4YjczNTFmYmJlNDg3N2UxZDJlODg0NDFjNjEyZjhhYWM4YTk4MTMzZDk0NjUyY2ZkNjY0MTUzZWZjYjVlIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 07-May-2018 08:22:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
X-RateLimit-Limit: 300
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 299
```

This returns `401` Unauthorized, I am not sure why? The problem is with `API` calls which is made by my `own web-application` using `Ajax` only. For Mobile App and Third-Party apps, we're using `Authorization` header and everything seems working OK with it. Can anybody let me know what am I missing or how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you specify the `api` middleware in your group? `'middleware'=>['api', 'auth:api']]`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, it returns unauthorized for /dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tracing, I found the issue was there with `app/Http/Kernel.php`. 
In  `protected $middlewareGroups` there are some `middlewares` added within `api` section like:

`protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:300,1',
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        'bindings',
    ],
];`

These were encrypting the cookie hence it was returning `401 Unauthorised`. I have removed them like:

`protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:300,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];`

and the code started working.